# installing ruby 1.9.3 of osx mavricsmavrics

Tags: ruby, osx-mavericks

I am trying to install ruby 1.9.3 on my osx 10.9 operating system and I keep getting the following error :

```
Error running 'requirements_osx_port_update_system ruby-1.9.3-p448',
please read /Users/ramesh/.rvm/log/1383430694_ruby-1.9.3-p448/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I am using the following command to do the installtion :

```
 rvm install 1.9.3
```

The complete log is as given below :

```
 checking for Tcl configuration... configure: error: Can't find Tcl configuration  definitions
 Command failed: cd /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base && CC=/usr/bin/cc ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-tclpackage=/Library/Tcl --with-install-user=root --with-install-group=admin --with-directory-mode=0755 --enable-readline && make && make install SELFUPDATING=1
Exit code: 1
DEBUG: Error installing new MacPorts base: command execution failed
while executing
"macports::selfupdate [array get global_options] base_updated"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error installing new MacPorts base: command execution failed
```

Requirements update log :

```
checking for Tcl configuration... configure: error: Can't find Tcl configuration definitions
Command failed: cd /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base && CC=/usr/bin/cc ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-tclpackage=/Library/Tcl --with-install-user=root --with-install-group=admin --with-directory-mode=0755 --enable-readline && make && make install SELFUPDATING=1
Exit code: 1
DEBUG: Error installing new MacPorts base: command execution failed
while executing
"macports::selfupdate [array get global_options] base_updated"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error installing new MacPorts base: command execution failed
```

Comment: Could you please post the log.

Comment: added the log could you please help me out now ?.

Comment: run the following commands `rvm get latest; rvm reload; rvm requirements` and make sure you have installed all requirements as recommended before installing `ruby`

Comment: I did what you said but still I get an error. The error log is given in the question above.

Comment: It seems I get the same error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I had to install the new command line tools for osx 10.9 (Mavrics) using the following command.

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Then I had to run the following command to do the macports selfupdate.

```
sudo port -v selfupdate
```

Then I can successfull install ruby 1.9.3 using the following command.

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Hope this will be helpful to anyone facing the same dilema.

Comment: any idea of how to solve it in 10.8? There is not --install command option.  

    Usage: xcode-select --print-path  
               Prints the path of the active Xcode folder  
       or: xcode-select --switch <xcode_path>  
               Sets the path for the active Xcode folder  
       or: xcode-select --version  
               Prints the version of xcode-select

Answer (score 0):

On my computer (running mavericks), it seemed like xcode's command line tools were installed because I had access to gcc, git, etc. But there was a small additional package I had to download by doing:

```
$ sudo xcode-select --install
```

This prompts to install the command line tools. Followed by `$ rvm requirements` the rvm prerequisites installed properly and I was able to install ruby.